# Basic approach on drawing multiple objects on screen using OpenGL

Tags: opengl

I was wondering how basic animation is done in OpenGL. In my code I currently insert all vertices for 2 shapes in a VBO. Then I select certain vertices ( shape's 1 vertices for example and change their "x" position by +1). Then I re-draw the image. Is this the correct way and idea of manipulating multiple object's position in Opengl?

Comment: You have been asking questions at least twice a day, essentially asking us to piece together some ball of source that you're working on. You have repeatedly been urged to visit a number of websites that would answer most of your current and future questions. Yet you systematically refuse to do so. Have you wondered if you are in fact a [Help Vampire?](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/) I urge you to use some of your own initiative and the plenitude of available online resources to solve problems, and ask us only when that has been exhausted.

Comment: Dear Nicol Bolas, you do realize that sometimes time is limited? especially if somebody is a uni student? I my be looking for quick answers and be a "help vampire" or whatever you call it, cause I have no other choice. When you are under pressure and you have deadlines sometimes this is the only way. Even with perfect time management you can't do it. Computer Graphics is really interesting and that's what I want to do, after I am done. Take my time and study this in depth. But I don't have time now. You do realize how universities function? My priority are deadlines now.

Comment: Nevertheless I would like to thank you for helping me out. And the tutorial you showed me, might be the best I found out there. When I have time I will make sure to go through it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is it depends on what your vertices represent. If you need to deform the model they represent, then yes you have to modify their coordinates. However, if the model retains its shape, you can use the modelview matrix to move the object.

If you currently use 1 draw call with the vertices of multiple shapes that move independently, this means you will have to make instead 1 draw call per shape with different modelview matrices.

This approach can slow down your rendering however depending on what you draw. If you have many simple shapes that move independently (e.g. a particle system), you will get poor performance by performing many draw calls and your approach is better. A potentially even better one (and more advanced), if it applies to your case, is to use the vertex shader to move the vertices according to a mathematical formula.

There are many other factors that affect rendering time, but small rendering batch size is high on the list.

I suggest you take a look at the [OpenGL red book](http://fly.cc.fer.hr/~unreal/theredbook/) chapter 3 for more info on matrices. The rest of the book is getting out of date with shaders and VBOs, but that part is good in my opinion.